# Azure FunctionApp Dependency Injection Error only if deploying through Azure Devops

Tags: c#, azure-devops, dependency-injection, azure-functions, pipeline

When I deploy my function app with the command
`func azure functionapp publish '<name>' --dotnet` it successfully packages my code and publishes it to the function app, and everything works.

I'm now working on building out automation pipelines, and I created a pipeline with the following stages

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 6 Core sdk'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.402'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
```

which packages the app and

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              slotName: $(slotName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              Action: 'Swap Slots'
              WebAppName: $(functionAppName)
              ResourceGroupName: 'group-name'
              SourceSlot: $(slotName)
              SwapWithProduction: true
```

It builds perfectly fine and then it also deploys and swaps the function app slots without any error.

The issue is that after it does this, everything is broken when making requests the function endpoints. I either get 404 errors saying my function endpoints don't exist, or I get 500 dependency injection errors. To escape this chaos I locally run `func azure functionapp publish '<name>' --dotnet` again on the exact same code that was deployed through the pipeline and then everything works fine.

I also tried deploying straight to the production slot instead of swapping, and the result is the same through the pipeline.

I am using the exact same version of dotnet locally as I am in the pipeline. Without any good errors to help me understand why it says it deployed without issue but everything is broken, it's hard for me to figure out what's going on.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Here is the dependency Injection error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Api.Request.Services.User' while attempting to activate
> 'Api.Request.Functions.Create'.at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)at
> lambda_method331(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] )at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider) at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
> : 42at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx
> functionInstance) at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
> : 31at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 20at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx
> functionInstance) at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs
> : 26at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx
> functionInstance) at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs
> : 44at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize()
> at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
> : 791at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance
> functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
> : 104

but I am including it in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<Services.User>();
```

Also, I am using in-process function apps, could that be why everything is breaking in the pipeline? I just don't get why it works perfect if I use the `func` command and doesn't work at all when I use the function azure provides in the pipeline. Isn't this all MS, so shouldn't the underlying publish mechanisms be the same?

**EDIT**

One thing I've just found is that the files in `/home/wwwroot` are different when deploying through the pipeline and through the `func azure functionapp` command. When deploying through the pipeline it has a lot more files in it. I'm wondering if it's building the project incorrectly..

Comment: What happens if you update your build process to use the same process you've discovered that works locally? There's no requirements to use the out-of-the-box tasks, especially if you've found a working CLI alternative. Conversely, can you replicate the problem on your local environment? That's going to be the first step to solving it.

Comment: The issue was that I had thought I was building/zipping and deploying my code correctly, but it wasn't being packaged the same way that it was locally, so I took your advice, took a step back, and altered how I was building/publishing to better match my local dev. Using Kudu to view the deployed files was a big help in realizing that things weren't deploying how I thought they were. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: I appreciate the reminder! Have a great day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had thought I was building/zipping and deploying my code correctly, but it wasn't being packaged the same way that it was locally.

Using Kudu to view the deployed files showed me that everything was being placed in the /home/wwwroot directory instead of having most of the built files being placed in the /bin directory. This explained why I was getting the unexpected behavior. After I altered my build script, I was able to get it to properly build and deploy my code changes.